# Xtext testing framework in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: xtext, deprecation-warning, eclipse-oxygen

I've got a quite large codebase in Xtext. Today I tried to use the new Eclipse Oxygen. In my Xtext unit-testing package, I've now got a lot of deprecated warnings regarding everything coming from `org.eclipse.xtext.junit4` package (like `@RunWith`, `@InjectWith`, `XtextRunner` and so on). By googling, I found out, that apparenty the package `org.eclipse.xtext.testing` should be used instead (see for example here: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-xtend/issues/29). However I get the error message in Eclipse `"org.eclipse.xtext.testing.XXXX cannot be resolved to a type"`. Why? Where do I get that package? My auto-completion in Eclipse does not propose anything for `org.eclipse.xtext.testing`. I have the standard "Eclipse for DSL developers" distribution (Oxygen). Here are my environment details.

```
Eclipse DSL Tools

Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800

  Xtext Complete SDK    2.12.0.v20170519-1412   org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group Eclipse Xtext
    MWE 2 language SDK  2.9.1.201705291011  org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.sdk.feature.group Eclipse Xtext
    Xbase   2.12.0.v20170519-1412   org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.feature.group   Eclipse Xtext
    Xbase Library   2.12.0.v20170518-0758   org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.feature.group   Eclipse Xtext
    Xtend IDE   2.12.0.v20170519-1412   org.eclipse.xtend.sdk.feature.group Eclipse Xtend
    Xtext Documentation 2.12.0.v20170519-0809   org.eclipse.xtext.docs.feature.group    Eclipse Xtext
    Xtext Examples  2.12.0.v20170519-1412   org.eclipse.xtext.examples.feature.group    Eclipse Xtext
    Xtext Redistributable   2.12.0.v20170519-1412   org.eclipse.xtext.redist.feature.group  Eclipse Xtext
    Xtext Runtime   2.12.0.v20170519-1412   org.eclipse.xtext.runtime.feature.group Eclipse Xtext
    Xtext UI    2.12.0.v20170519-1412   org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.group  Eclipse Xtext
    Xtext Xtext UI  2.12.0.v20170519-1412   org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.feature.group    Eclipse Xtext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `org.eclipse.xtext.testing` is not yet on your bundles classpath. Please make sure you add it to the required bundles in your `manifest.mf`.

Comment: That was the case. I had `org.eclipse.xtext.junit4` there from my previous Eclipse version. I replaced it to `org.eclipse.xtext.testing` now and it solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your answer, helpful as always!